# How to retrive time from standard look up field in opportunity

Tags: apex, community, opportunity, lookup, datetime

Hi i got a requirement like to get time in standard look up called CreatedBy in opportunity page.

Is it possible to retrieve only time from that field.

Because it is Look up relationship of user.I tried with custom field it works fine.But i don't have any idea reagrding this issue.Please help me guys if anyone face this issue

Comment: You want the time from CreatedBy field ?? or from createddate

Comment: Is it possible with createdBy field @prady

Comment: Ya i want to get from CreatedBy field because it shows difference in time variation.@Prady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to extract time form created date in opportunity page use this formula.

```
LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT ( CreatedDate ),9),8)
```

Here is the complete formula which display time in 12 hour format -

```
IF( VALUE(( LEFT(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT ( CreatedDate ),9),8), 2) )) > 12 , 
      TEXT(VALUE(( LEFT(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT ( CreatedDate ),9),8), 2) )) -12) + RIGHT(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT ( CreatedDate ),9),8), 6) , 
   LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT ( CreatedDate ),9),8))
```

Comment: Hey thanks and how to convert the format in to 12 hours..@Rachit

Comment: Use a if statement .. trim the hour value(hr) if its greater then 12 then change the hr accordingly(hr -12).

Comment: It doesn't helps in community i had already found similar answer given to some other question and you are just posting there answers here.If you want to answer just check if it works then only post thanks @Rachit

Comment: But i think i was clear on how to do it once you have a text value in 24 hr format.. but anyways @Pavan here is your complete formula.

Comment: sorry i had already wrote another formula it works fine but i am facing issue with AM or PM sometimes.I think your formula should work fine@Rachit

Comment: It Worked fine But i already got with other formula also but i face problems sometimes with AM & PM.That's why i made up vote to your Answer.But it didn't resolve my issue totally.I am working on it @Rachit